# Edit for uploading images to a database

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

Just finished creating a file upload function; for images to be uploaded to a database. This is working fine.

The code below is a shortened version of the controller with just one image in it.

```
    [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Create(CarAdvert caradvert,
                 HttpPostedFileBase picture1)
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {

                    if (picture1 != null)
                    {
                        string image1 = picture1.FileName;
                        caradvert.Image1 = image1;
                        var image1Path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images"), image1);
                        picture1.SaveAs(image1Path);
                    }
db.CarAdverts.Add(caradvert);
                 db.SaveChanges();
                 return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

When a record is created all images upload fine; the code in the controller works, it is just when I try and edit the uploaded images the problem arises. The images will not save.

```
[HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Edit(CarAdvert caradvert,  HttpPostedFileBase picture1)
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {

                    if (picture1 != null)
                    {
                        string image1 = picture1.FileName;
                        caradvert.Image1 = image1;
                        var image1Path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images"), image1);
                        picture1.SaveAs(image1Path);
                    }


                db.Entry(caradvert).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to attached the "caradvert" Entity to DbContext. Try this in Edit Function.

```
db.CarAdverts.Attach(caradvert);  // Entity is in Unchanged state
db.Entry(caradvert).State = EntityState.Modified;

db.SaveChanges();
```